# How to check objects collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that 3 objects(boxColliders)are checked for collisions with other Cubes.If collision is TRUE the object script must inform the Player.How to move between two scripts? If the objects collides with cubes ,the player can't move to this direction.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40UbG.png)

I tried something like this but script checked only the player.

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo){
      if(collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {

        Debug.Log ("collision");
    }

}
```

This is full player code

```
private Vector3 offset;

public GameObject player;
public GameObject center;

public GameObject right;
public GameObject left;


public int step=9;

public float speed =(float) 0.01;

bool input=true;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {


    if(input==true)
    {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {

            StartCoroutine ("moveRight");
            input = false;

        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
            StartCoroutine ("moveLeft");
            input = false;
        }

    }

}


 IEnumerator moveLeft(){

    for(int i=0;i<(90/step);i++){

        player.transform.RotateAround (left.transform.position, Vector3.forward, step);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (speed);
    }
    center.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    input = true;

}

 IEnumerator moveRight(){

    for(int i=0;i<  (90/step);i++){
        player.transform.RotateAround (right.transform.position, Vector3.back, step);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (speed);
    }
    center.transform.position = player.transform.position;
    input = true;

}

void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo){
    if(collisionInfo.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {

        Debug.Log ("collision");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put colliders and collision events on all the GameObjects that you want to recognize collisions for. If you just want to access the script of the other objects and you aren't sure which object you're colliding with you can do something like this:

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    var cubeScript = collisionInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<CubeScriptTypeHere>();        
    var playerScript = collisionInfo.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerScriptTypeHere>();

    if(cubeScript != null)
    {
        //This object hit a cube
        //Do something with cubeScript
    }
    if(playerScript != null)
    {
        //This object hit a player
       //Do something with playerScript
    }
}
```

Obviously replace "ScriptTypeHere" with whatever you named the actual scripts. Then you can access all of the public methods, properties, etc. of external scripts from your collision event.